# How to use redis for notifications in NodeJS/MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, notifications, redis, push-notification

I have running on NodeJs/MongoDB and Android/HTML client where people are able to follow posts, I store their ids in an array of followers in the post's document. 
I want to implement a notification feature when a new comment comes I want to notify all the followers.

So, I have looked across the web but I couldn't get one tutorial where I understood exactly how things work.

I have seen many recommend the Redis Pub/Sub, but from what I have read Redis is a in-memory database, so I was thinking, I could create a channel in Redis with the post's Id, when the user follows that post I would subscribe him to the channel, then when a new comment comes i just publish to the channel. Is this how it works?? If so, then how about when the user goes off then comes back in later, And how about when there are many posts, won't Redis clear the channel then I wouldn't be able to send the notification to all the followers?

I think I'm understanding it all wrong,I'd appreciate your help. How exactly can I be able to send a notification to all followers?

Comment: seems like it will get losts if client got disconnected http://redis.io/topics/notifications

Comment: A way more reliable way would be to use JMS topics. After entering a new entry, send a JMS message to the topic containing the `_id` field and let the users query then.